# WCF Certificate Store from SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, wcf, certificate, store

I have a SQL Database which is storing my client side certificate for WCF service and other services. (X509 etc). I would like to use this Store (instead of 'My') to retrive this certificate (instead of declaring it in web.config) and then use it for WCF.

I have tried to search on this site and google but does not seems to be much of a help.

Currently I am doing

```
 var targetEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(targetLogicalAddress, targetIdentity);
 MyTransportPortTypesClient proxy = new MyTransportPortTypesClient("WebConfigSection", targetEndpoint);
```

So ideally I would like to get rid of the "WebConfigSection" and instead pass some sort of WCF object which has certifictate signed.

Does anyone know how to achive this?

---

I have finally solved this and Here's how I did it. (I'll share my experiece so everyone can use it) This is without using any machine CertificateStore. Its purely from Database to the client Proxy.

I have created X509Certificate2 Object and assign physical file (in byte[]). You can also put password if its password protected.

Then I have assigned the certificate to my proxy client. 
Something like :

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate = __MyCertificate
```

Now I have manupulated my clientproxy as I was inteneted to in my app.config. and that's it. All these properties will be in your proxy object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is at least very difficult, if not down right impossible. WCF uses [SChannel SSPI provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380123%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for the authentication and this SSPI provider will load certificates only from the [SChannel CSP provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In order to use a certificate from the database the certificate would have to be loaded first into a [PROV_RSA_SCHANNEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) CSP keystore and then the certificate context of this keystore would be passed to [`AcquireCredentialsHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For instance, this is how [database mirroring is able to authenticate using a certificate stored in the database](http://rusanu.com/2008/10/23/how-does-certificate-based-authentication-work/). While it is possible to do all these steps in managed code too, I'm not sure if is possible to plug them into WCF: I *expect* it is, but probably not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Does this mean there is no 'regular/less difficult' way to achive this. i.e. the cerificate has to be in Machine's certificate store and it has to be declared in config?

Comment: One way of ('try to') doing this is to do what ever is done in web.config. file. I.e. Creating objects and properties in codes? Any thoughts?